# Buscar o nome e o CPF dos médicos que têm consultas marcadas com todos os pacientes

Tags: postgresql

No postgres, como Buscar o nome e o CPF dos médicos que têm consultas marcadas com todos os pacientes?

Chaves:
Paciente: id_paciente
Medico: id_medico
consulta: id_paciente, id_medico

Comment: Toda consulta precisa de parâmetros lógicos para que seu resultado seja correto, no seu caso se faz necessário incluir outros campos de ambas tabelas, edite sua pergunta colocando todos os campos de cada uma. E se possível a query que você está tentando fazer dar certo.

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa selecionar todos os ids de médicos presentes na tabela de consulta, e fazer um join para buscar os dados do respectivo médico, veja o código abaixo:

```
SELECT distinct 
    c.id_medico,
    m.nome as nome_medico,
    m.cpf as cpf_medico
FROM consultas c
LEFT OUTER JOIN medicos m on m.id = c.id_medico
```

Quando for postar uma pergunta, poste também a estrutura que tem o seu banco de dados e o código que está utilizando.

Answer (score 1):

Assumindo que sua estrutura de tabelas seja algo parecido com isso:

```
CREATE TABLE  paciente
(
    id_paciente INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    nome TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE  medico
(
    id_medico INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    nome text,
    cpf text
);

CREATE TABLE consulta
(
    id_paciente INTEGER,
    id_medico INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY ( id_paciente ) REFERENCES paciente ( id_paciente ),
    FOREIGN KEY ( id_medico ) REFERENCES medico ( id_medico )
);
```

Com a seguinte carga de teste:

```
INSERT INTO paciente ( id_paciente, nome ) VALUES ( 1, 'Joao' );
INSERT INTO paciente ( id_paciente, nome ) VALUES ( 2, 'Maria' );
INSERT INTO paciente ( id_paciente, nome ) VALUES ( 3, 'Jose' );
INSERT INTO paciente ( id_paciente, nome ) VALUES ( 4, 'Ana' );
INSERT INTO paciente ( id_paciente, nome ) VALUES ( 5, 'Luiz' );

INSERT INTO medico ( id_medico, nome, cpf ) VALUES ( 1, 'Oswaldo Cruz', '123.123.123-00' );
INSERT INTO medico ( id_medico, nome, cpf ) VALUES ( 2, 'Carlos Chagas', '900.900.900-99' );
INSERT INTO medico ( id_medico, nome, cpf ) VALUES ( 3, 'Vital Brazil', '111.222.333-99' );
INSERT INTO medico ( id_medico, nome, cpf ) VALUES ( 4, 'Ze Ninguem', '000.000.000.-00' );

INSERT INTO consulta ( id_paciente, id_medico ) VALUES ( 1, 1 );
INSERT INTO consulta ( id_paciente, id_medico ) VALUES ( 2, 1 );
INSERT INTO consulta ( id_paciente, id_medico ) VALUES ( 3, 1 );
INSERT INTO consulta ( id_paciente, id_medico ) VALUES ( 4, 2 );
INSERT INTO consulta ( id_paciente, id_medico ) VALUES ( 5, 2 );
INSERT INTO consulta ( id_paciente, id_medico ) VALUES ( 2, 3 );
INSERT INTO consulta ( id_paciente, id_medico ) VALUES ( 4, 3 );
```

A consulta ficaria assim:

```
SELECT
    m.cpf AS cpf_medico,
    m.nome AS nome_medico,
    p.nome AS nome_paciente
FROM
    consulta c
JOIN
    medico m ON ( c.id_medico = m.id_medico )
JOIN
    paciente p ON ( c.id_paciente = p.id_paciente )
ORDER BY 
    m.cpf;
```

Saída:

```
|     cpf_medico |   nome_medico | nome_paciente |
|----------------|---------------|---------------|
| 111.222.333-99 |  Vital Brazil |         Maria |
| 111.222.333-99 |  Vital Brazil |           Ana |
| 123.123.123-00 |  Oswaldo Cruz |          Jose |
| 123.123.123-00 |  Oswaldo Cruz |          Joao |
| 123.123.123-00 |  Oswaldo Cruz |         Maria |
| 900.900.900-99 | Carlos Chagas |           Ana |
| 900.900.900-99 | Carlos Chagas |          Luiz |
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/52af4/1)

Comment: O JOIN só pega os valores em comum, não? Caso não tenha passará batido.. que seria o caso de algum LEFT/RIGHT JOIN da vida.. ou até mesmo full join com condições..

Comment: Nunca passará batido pois uma `Consulta` é a composição de um `Medico` e um `Paciente`. Editei a resposta incluindo explicitamente as chaves estrangeiras na tabela `consulta`. Isso garante que nenhuma `Consulta` será inserida se não houver um `Médico` e um `Paciente`.